# How do references pointing to themselves work in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am currently experimenting while trying to learn Rust.
I see that it is possible to make a reference point to its own address (`y = &y` below), however, for some reason, the program is still able to find what the reference was initially pointing at;

```rust
let x = 1;
let mut y = &x;
println!("{y:p} -> {y}"); // 0x7fffb13d6f6c -> 1
y = &y;
println!("{y:p} -> {y}"); // 0x7fffb13d6f6c -> 1
```

What I understand is that after the second line, the memory looks like the following;

| name | address | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | a1 | 1 |
| y | a2 | a1 |

If the instruction `y = &y` was turning the memory into this;

| name | address | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | a1 | 1 |
| y | a2 | a2 |

`println!` would be able to output what it outputs on the last line, so what does the fourth line does exactly and what does the memory look like after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` does not point at itself. This is impossible. `y` points exactly where it pointed before, and the assignment `y = &y` does nothing.

So what does it mean, and why does it compile?

To answer this question we need to look at the types. And there is something mysterious here: if `y` has the type `&i32`, then `&y` has the type `&&i32`, so how are you able to assign `&y` to `y` while they are completely different types?

The answer is deref coercion. When you're writing `y = &y`, the compiler tries to match the types. It cannot match `&&i32` with `&i32`, but it tries to be helpful and it thinks: "probably, the programmer had some reference that he want to dereference but just didn't write it out explicitly. So I will do that for him!" This is useful, for example, to pass `&String` to a function taking `&str`. `&String` is not the same type as `&str`, but `String` derefs to `str`, so we can transform this to `&**s`, to first create a `String` from the `&String`, then create `str` from that, then finnaly take a reference to that to create a `&str`.

So, `y = &y` is equivalent to `y = &*y`. Which just takes a reference then immediately dereference it, that is, just copies the value in `y` into `y` again, effectively preserving it.